# HOw to avoid Concurrent modification exception while using collections in java

Tags: android

How to avoid concurrent modification exception in the following code?
BeanList is a list of Bean objects

```
Bean bean = BeanList.get(0);
List<Bean> tempList = BeanList.subList(1, BeanList.size());
Collections.sort(tempList);
tempList.add(0, bean);
BeanList.clear();
BeanList.addAll(tempList);
```

Comment: Is BeanList a class of your's? If so, could you add the relevant parts of the BeanList class to your question?

Comment: Bean class

 public final class Bean implements Comparable<Bean>,Serializable{





  private Date postDate;




  public Date getPostDate() {




  return ((postDate == null) ? new Date() : postDate);




 }






 public void setPostDate(Date postDate) {




  this.postDate = postDate;



 }




     @Override



 public int compareTo(Bean bean) {




      return (bean.getPostDate().compareTo(this.postDate));






 }




   }

Comment: I was referring to the BeanLIST class. And could you add it to the question, not to the comments, its hardly readable. But I suspect a synchronization issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As future reference. Try to reduce your problem into a minimal compiling example. It makes our job easier. Describe all your data types in your question. Here we have to guess what the data type of your BeanList is. Also adhere to Java naming conventions. Class names start with capital letter. Member variables start with small letter (i.e. beanList instead of BeanList). Incorrectly formatted code is hard for us, the people you want help from, to read. Provide a stack trace and tell what line in your code causes the exception.

Your problem is not in the Bean class or synchronization.

Your problem is in the way you operate on the sublist.

List.subList() does not really create a new list. It creates a "view" into the existing list and it shares data structures with the original list. When you clear the contents of the original list, you also clear the content of the sublist and when you then try to access the sublist (the data of which has been changed) you get the exception.

Create a new list to which you add all the elements from the sublist.

```
    List<Bean> tempList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
    tempList.addAll(list.subList(1, list.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava.

First, import:

> api 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android

Then use code below:

```
Collections2.orderedPermutations(userList, new Comparator<BrandMenuHeaderModel>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(UserModel m1, UserModel cm) {
                    return m1.getName() - m2.getName();
                }
            });
```